# NetworkX error while loading pajek network

Tags: python, networkx, pajek

I'm trying to load a network in pajek format .net into a graph in python. It seems to be an easy task, but I'm getting an error that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "insta.py", line 4, in <module>
      G = nx.read_pajek("instaedges.net")
   File "<decorator-gen-588>", line 2, in read_pajek
   File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 240, in _open_file
      result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\networkx\pajek.py", line 163, in read_pajek
      return parse_pajek(lines)
   File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\pajek.py", line 205, in parse_pajek
      l, nnodes = l.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

my code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_pajek("instaedges.net")
print(nx.info(G))
```

What is the problem here?
I'm using NetworkX 2.2 and python 3.7.0

Comment: Potentially, "instaedges.net" is not in the correct format. Without the file, this will be impossible to determine though. I would link to the file (put it on github, pastebin or google drive).

Comment: Yes, it semms that it is indeed the problem. Possibly the conversion of formats was faulty. Thanks!